# Game Multiplayer converstion websockets

Tags: javascript, websocket, multiplayer

I've found a cool bit of code online that I'm looking to adapt into a game, but firstly I want to get multiplayer working on it using sockets like socket.io, express or eureca.io, but I'm not sure how to adapt the code I have to multiplayer, could anyone lend me a hand and show me how to do it?

Regards

A confused individual

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<center><canvas id="gameCanvas" width="600" height="600"></canvas></center>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var socket = io.connect();
window.Game = {};
    (function(){
        function Rectangle(left, top, width, height){
            this.left = left || 0;
            this.top = top || 0;
            this.width = width || 0;
            this.height = height || 0;
            this.right = this.left + this.width;
            this.bottom = this.top + this.height;
        }

        Rectangle.prototype.set = function(left, top, /*optional*/width, /*optional*/height){
            this.left = left;
            this.top = top;
            this.width = width || this.width;
            this.height = height || this.height
            this.right = (this.left + this.width);
            this.bottom = (this.top + this.height);
        }

        Rectangle.prototype.within = function(r) {
            return (r.left <= this.left && 
                    r.right >= this.right &&
                    r.top <= this.top && 
                    r.bottom >= this.bottom);
        }       

        Rectangle.prototype.overlaps = function(r) {
            return (this.left < r.right && 
                    r.left < this.right && 
                    this.top < r.bottom &&
                    r.top < this.bottom);
        }

        // add "class" Rectangle to our Game object
        Game.Rectangle = Rectangle;
    })();   

    // wrapper for "class" Camera (avoid global objects)
    (function(){

        // possibles axis to move the camera
        var AXIS = {
            NONE: "none", 
            HORIZONTAL: "horizontal", 
            VERTICAL: "vertical", 
            BOTH: "both"
        };

        // Camera constructor
        function Camera(xView, yView, canvasWidth, canvasHeight, worldWidth, worldHeight)
        {
            // position of camera (left-top coordinate)
            this.xView = xView || 0;
            this.yView = yView || 0;

            // distance from followed object to border before camera starts move
            this.xDeadZone = 0; // min distance to horizontal borders
            this.yDeadZone = 0; // min distance to vertical borders

            // viewport dimensions
            this.wView = canvasWidth;
            this.hView = canvasHeight;          

            // allow camera to move in vertical and horizontal axis
            this.axis = AXIS.BOTH;  

            // object that should be followed
            this.followed = null;

            // rectangle that represents the viewport
            this.viewportRect = new Game.Rectangle(this.xView, this.yView, this.wView, this.hView);             

            // rectangle that represents the world's boundary (room's boundary)
            this.worldRect = new Game.Rectangle(0, 0, worldWidth, worldHeight);

        }

        // gameObject needs to have "x" and "y" properties (as world(or room) position)
        Camera.prototype.follow = function(gameObject, xDeadZone, yDeadZone)
        {       
            this.followed = gameObject; 
            this.xDeadZone = xDeadZone;
            this.yDeadZone = yDeadZone;
        }                   

        Camera.prototype.update = function()
        {
            // keep following the player (or other desired object)
            if(this.followed != null)
            {       
                if(this.axis == AXIS.HORIZONTAL || this.axis == AXIS.BOTH)
                {       
                    // moves camera on horizontal axis based on followed object position
                    if(this.followed.x - this.xView  + this.xDeadZone > this.wView)
                        this.xView = this.followed.x - (this.wView - this.xDeadZone);
                    else if(this.followed.x  - this.xDeadZone < this.xView)
                        this.xView = this.followed.x  - this.xDeadZone;

                }
                if(this.axis == AXIS.VERTICAL || this.axis == AXIS.BOTH)
                {
                    // moves camera on vertical axis based on followed object position
                    if(this.followed.y - this.yView + this.yDeadZone > this.hView)
                        this.yView = this.followed.y - (this.hView - this.yDeadZone);
                    else if(this.followed.y - this.yDeadZone < this.yView)
                        this.yView = this.followed.y - this.yDeadZone;
                }                       

            }       

            // update viewportRect
            this.viewportRect.set(this.xView, this.yView);

            // don't let camera leaves the world's boundary
            if(!this.viewportRect.within(this.worldRect))
            {
                if(this.viewportRect.left < this.worldRect.left)
                    this.xView = this.worldRect.left;
                if(this.viewportRect.top < this.worldRect.top)                  
                    this.yView = this.worldRect.top;
                if(this.viewportRect.right > this.worldRect.right)
                    this.xView = this.worldRect.right - this.wView;
                if(this.viewportRect.bottom > this.worldRect.bottom)                    
                    this.yView = this.worldRect.bottom - this.hView;
            }

        }   

        // add "class" Camera to our Game object
        Game.Camera = Camera;

    })();

    // wrapper for "class" Player
    (function(){
        function Player(x, y){
            // (x, y) = center of object
            // ATTENTION:
            // it represents the player position on the world(room), not the canvas position
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;             

            // move speed in pixels per second
            this.speed = 200;       

            // render properties
            this.width = 50;
            this.height = 50;
        }

        Player.prototype.update = function(step, worldWidth, worldHeight){
            // parameter step is the time between frames ( in seconds )

            // check controls and move the player accordingly
            if(Game.controls.left)
                this.x -= this.speed * step;
            if(Game.controls.up)
                this.y -= this.speed * step;
            if(Game.controls.right)
                this.x += this.speed * step;
            if(Game.controls.down)
                this.y += this.speed * step;        

            // don't let player leaves the world's boundary
            if(this.x - this.width/2 < 0){
                this.x = this.width/2;
            }
            if(this.y - this.height/2 < 0){
                this.y = this.height/2;
            }
            if(this.x + this.width/2 > worldWidth){
                this.x = worldWidth - this.width/2;
            }
            if(this.y + this.height/2 > worldHeight){
                this.y = worldHeight - this.height/2;
            }
        }

        Player.prototype.draw = function(context, xView, yView){        
            // draw a simple rectangle shape as our player model
            context.save();     
            context.fillStyle = "black";
            // before draw we need to convert player world's position to canvas position            
            context.fillRect((this.x-this.width/2) - xView, (this.y-this.height/2) - yView, this.width, this.height);
            context.restore();          
        }

        // add "class" Player to our Game object
        Game.Player = Player;

    })();

    // wrapper for "class" Map
    (function(){
        function Map(width, height){
            // map dimensions
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;

            // map texture
            this.image = null;
        }

        // generate an example of a large map
        Map.prototype.generate = function(){
            var ctx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");        
            ctx.canvas.width = this.width;
            ctx.canvas.height = this.height;        

            var rows = ~~(this.width/44) + 1;
            var columns = ~~(this.height/44) + 1;


            ctx.restore();  

            // store the generate map as this image texture
            this.image = new Image();
            this.image.src = ctx.canvas.toDataURL("image/png");                 

            // clear context
            ctx = null;
        }

        // draw the map adjusted to camera
        Map.prototype.draw = function(context, xView, yView){                   
            // easiest way: draw the entire map changing only the destination coordinate in canvas
            // canvas will cull the image by itself (no performance gaps -> in hardware accelerated environments, at least)
            //context.drawImage(this.image, 0, 0, this.image.width, this.image.height, -xView, -yView, this.image.width, this.image.height);

            // didactic way:

            var sx, sy, dx, dy;
            var sWidth, sHeight, dWidth, dHeight;

            // offset point to crop the image
            sx = xView;
            sy = yView;

            // dimensions of cropped image          
            sWidth =  context.canvas.width;
            sHeight = context.canvas.height;

            // if cropped image is smaller than canvas we need to change the source dimensions
            if(this.image.width - sx < sWidth){
                sWidth = this.image.width - sx;
            }
            if(this.image.height - sy < sHeight){
                sHeight = this.image.height - sy; 
            }

            // location on canvas to draw the croped image
            dx = 0;
            dy = 0;
            // match destination with source to not scale the image
            dWidth = sWidth;
            dHeight = sHeight;                                  

            context.drawImage(this.image, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight);            
        }

        // add "class" Map to our Game object
        Game.Map = Map;

    })();

    // Game Script
    (function(){
        // prepaire our game canvas
        var canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

        // game settings:   
        var FPS = 30;
        var INTERVAL = 1000/FPS; // milliseconds
        var STEP = INTERVAL/1000 // seconds

        // setup an object that represents the room
        var room = {
            width: 600,
            height: 600,
            map: new Game.Map(600, 600)
        };

        // generate a large image texture for the room
        room.map.generate();

        // setup player
        var player = new Game.Player(50, 50);

        // setup the magic camera !!!
        var camera = new Game.Camera(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, room.width, room.height);       
        camera.follow(player, canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2);

        // Game update function
        var update = function(){            
            player.update(STEP, room.width, room.height);
            camera.update();
        }

        // Game draw function
        var draw = function(){
            // clear the entire canvas
            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            // redraw all objects
            room.map.draw(context, camera.xView, camera.yView);     
            player.draw(context, camera.xView, camera.yView);       
        }

        // Game Loop
        var gameLoop = function(){                      
            update();
            draw();
        }   

        // <-- configure play/pause capabilities:

        // I'll use setInterval instead of requestAnimationFrame for compatibility reason,
        // but it's easy to change that.

        var runningId = -1;

        Game.play = function(){ 
            if(runningId == -1){
                runningId = setInterval(function(){
                    gameLoop();
                }, INTERVAL);
                console.log("play");
            }
        }

        Game.togglePause = function(){      
            if(runningId == -1){
                Game.play();
            }
            else
            {
                clearInterval(runningId);
                runningId = -1;
                console.log("paused");
            }
        }   

        // -->

    })();

    // <-- configure Game controls:

    Game.controls = {
        left: false,
        up: false,
        right: false,
        down: false,
    };

    window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
        switch(e.keyCode)
        {
            case 37: // left arrow
                Game.controls.left = true;
                break;
            case 38: // up arrow
                Game.controls.up = true;
                break;
            case 39: // right arrow
                Game.controls.right = true;
                break;
            case 40: // down arrow
                Game.controls.down = true;
                break;
        }
    }, false);

    window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
        switch(e.keyCode)
        {
            case 37: // left arrow
                Game.controls.left = false;
                break;
            case 38: // up arrow
                Game.controls.up = false;
                break;
            case 39: // right arrow
                Game.controls.right = false;
                break;
            case 40: // down arrow
                Game.controls.down = false;
                break;
            case 80: // key P pauses the game
                Game.togglePause();
                break;      
        }
    }, false);

    // -->

    // start the game when page is loaded
    window.onload = function(){ 
        Game.play();
    }
    });
```

Comment: this site is intended for asking questions, not letting other people work for you for free. please show us what you've done, what you want to achieve and what are the actual problems you're facing.

Comment: I was asking where to start from.

Comment: then you might consider reading some books on game design ;) also, "where to start from" is still not a question: we can't tell you how to start doing something without knowing what you want to achieve. the only info about your project was that you stole "a cool bit of code" on the interwebs and want to do something multiplayer-capable.

Answer (score 0):

You create a canvas in Map.prototype.generate, and you select your existing canava in html at the end in Game Script (prepaire our game canvas)
It's normaly not worked ....